# Send Facebook message manually via extension / console

Tags: facebook, google-chrome-extension, sendmessage

I am having a problem with my code , I have tried a lot of ways but none of them is working for me.
I am creating something that can send a message automatically to a user. so here is a part of my code where `response.a` is the response text.
The problem is that it writes the text in the chat box but when you press enter the message is not sent , it freezes actually , I guess.

```js
// get proper response here
var message = {};
message.method = "getAnswer";
message.q = $(this).find("._5yl5 span").text();
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message, function(response) {
    if (typeof(response) != "undefined") {
        if (response.success == true) {
            // make some changes in elements that facebook makes its own when we go on to type message
            $(head).find("[contenteditable=true][aria-autocomplete=list]").focus();
            $(head).find("._1mf._1mj").find("span").find("[data-text=true]").remove();
            $(head).find("._1p1t").remove();
            $(head).find("[contenteditable=true][aria-autocomplete=list]").removeAttr("aria-describedby");
            $(head).find("._1mf._1mj").find("span").html("<span data-text='true'></span>")
            // Write the text in the box
            $(head).find("span[data-text=true]").text(response.a);
        }else{
            console.log(response.error);
        }
    }else{
        console.log("no response");
    }
});
```

This code writes down the response message to the chat box but when you click enter the message is not sent , but is actually messed (I don't know why .)

Comment: The posted info is not sufficient. What is `head`? Is it the `<head>` element? What is `messed` exactly? Is this code in a content script? What does code in the receiving end in chrome.runtime.onMessage callback do? Are there any errors in the console? Also note that directly setting text is often not compatible with custom editors. I'd focus the element and then `document.execCommand('insertText', false, 'foo')`

Comment: @wOxxOm head is the main selector which is equal to "this" and point is not what is being recieved from chrome response but is that why facebook does not allow me to send message with my text.

Comment: This code just manually writes code in the field but fb does not allow me to send that message...

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: If you are going to operate multiple times on a set of elements that is not going to change, then obtain it once and assign it to a variable (e.g. `$head = $(head)`). Why are you calling `.find("._1mf._1mj").find("span").find("[data-text=true]")` instead of `.find("._1mf._1mj span [data-text=true]")` (and other similar constructions)?